# Executing cmd with os.system via Python file called from PHP

Tags: php, python

Ok so, I have a problem where I'm unable to get a command to execute using the `os.system()` function. I've tried looking around but I couldn't find anything that helps me. I'll give a quick run-down of my goal.

I have a `LAMP` server running `Ubuntu 16.04` with `Python 2.7.12` installed, I have two files (located in the same directory):

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd("python pdfCreator.py a b c");
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

**pdfCreator.py**

```
import sys
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'outputs/template.xlsx')

sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']
sheet_ranges['A1'] = sys.argv[1]
sheet_ranges['A2'] = sys.argv[2]
sheet_ranges['A3'] = sys.argv[3]

wb.save("outputs/%s.xlsx" % sys.argv[1])

try:
    os.system("libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf \"outputs/%s.xlsx\" --outdir outputs/" % sys.argv[1] )   
except Exception as e:
    print "error: %s" % e

print "\"%s.xlsx\" created." % sys.argv[1]
```

My ultimate goal is to write some data to an `.xlsx` which I'm using as a template, `save as` that excel file into a new document and then convert the `.xlsx` into a `.pdf`. I have this working up until the PDF part.

I'm using the command `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf \"outputs/%s.xlsx\" --outdir outputs/" % sys.argv[1]` in conjunction with the `os.system` to do this however, I can't seem to get it to work. I've added a `try` `except` around the command, however I'm not getting any error outputs either. If I change `os.system` to `print()` and print the command to the screen and then paste it in my CLI, it works; which makes me think it's a permissions error.

All files that are created are done so within the `outputs/` directory, so I've `chown`ed the directory to www-data:

`drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data privacy 4096 Jul 20 08:55 outputs`

I've also tried with www-data having group as well, however neither work:

`drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 20 09:20 outputs`

I'm running out of options and ideas, if anyone is able to provide any suggestions I'm all for it, thanks.

If you need me to do anything or provide anymore information, just ask.

**----- EDIT -----**

After doing some more research into it, I've done the following:

As myself:
`libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf outputs/a.xlsx --outdir outputs/`

I get the following:

```
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
convert /var/www/html/requests/Example/outputs/a.xlsx -> /var/www
/html/requests/Example/outputs//a.pdf using filter : calc_pdf_Export
```

As `www-data` (accessed via `sudo -u www-data /bin/bash`):
`libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf outputs/a.xlsx --outdir outputs/`

I get:

```
[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
No protocol specified
```

Comment: Can you try executing our command with [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)? The shell might want to tell you something that gets lost because you do not read from its pty

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, but I've tried the two following commands and neither have given me any output?  `py2output = subprocess.check_output(['libreoffice','--headless','--convert-to', '\"outputs/a.xlsx\"', '--outdir outputs/'])` and `py2output = subprocess.check_output("libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf outputs/a.xlsx --outdir outputs/",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)` along with `print('py2 said:', py2output)`. I did sanity check this to make sure it was working with `py2output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])` and that did work.